# Where does iTunes store its playlists?

Tags: itunes, playlists

I have a drive that won't boot anymore, but I put the drive in an enclosure and I can access it fine.  So, I want to pull out my iTunes playlists, but I can't load up iTunes to export them.  Does anyone know how I can do this without booting into the system?

Comment: I have given you the answer in your other post, so this post is duplicated.

Comment: Kind of, I just saw your answer there thanks! But it would be more helpful for others to find this answer in a separate question, the other question is about how to boot an existing OS into another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes saves the settings, library inside the iTunes folder. IF you want to backup iTunes library, simply follow the instructions:

1. Install **iTunes** on your new drive.
2. After installation is finished, open **iTunes** for the first time and follow the instructions (don't search for media), this will make iTunes create the **iTunes** folders in your **My Music** folder.
3. Now, Go to **My Music** folder inside your old drive.
4. Copy **iTunes** folder that is located inside **My Music** folder.
5. Close **iTunes**, and go to My Music folder (on your new drive).
6. Replace the new **iTunes** folder with the one you copied from the old drive.
7. Re-launch **iTunes**, and your settings, playlists, music, all library will be there. (Make sure your music is in those folders, if it was outside of those folders you will need to first import your music, close **iTunes**, and when you re-open your playlists will be there).

**For data that ARE NOT synced with iTunes**

If you have other data that are inside your iDevice (iPhone, iPad), but you have not synced it with iTunes such as tones, songs, app, ..etc. You will have to use a third party tool such as **Syncios** to export them into your computer, then copy them into iTunes. Because if you sync your iDevice, it'll erase the current library inside your iDevice and replace it with the current iTunes library.

So, before you sync your iDevice, you have to copy whatever data that is not inside the iTunes library, and add them manually into the iTunes library. You can also use iTunes Store to download the data you purchased as well. To move the data that you exported from the iDevice, you just drag-n-drop the data you want to move into your iTunes library into its category (e.g Apps to Apps, Songs to Music). 
While the Photos you need to add them to the Photos folder that you use in iTunes.

Comment: Does this also work for iPad data?  I want to synchronize my playlists to add new music to my iPad, but since I lost my OS, will it recognize and sync or will it request me to erase the iPad? Basically are my backups in the iTunes folder too? (I would have just tried it but my iPad isn't home today)

Comment: @GiH post updated.

Answer (score 0):

It stores info in an iTunes Library.itl file. I'm not sure of the internal formal of this. It's probably subject to change on apples whim.

There's also, sometimes, an iTunes Library.xml file. This is not the blessed file, but it's what iTunes cares to export in a readable format (if you consider XML readable) to other apps on your system.

Good luck.